# Клиент-сервер. Как лучше оповещать клиента?

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокет

Пишу на C/C++ под Линукс. 
Ситуация: есть сервер, если клиент. Клиент запрашивает данные с сервера вызовом send(), ждет ответ вызовом recv(). Сервер в свою очередь слушает порт вызовом accept(), далее получает запрос через recv() и отвечает через send(). То есть клиент просит, сервер отвечает. Представим, что на сервере появляются данные для клиента.

Вопрос: есть ли механизм или решение, лучшее чем раз в секунду опрашивать сервер на наличие данных для клиента? Можно ведь и клиенту открыть сокет на вход, но разумно ли это, есть ли такая практика вообще?

Comment: В данный момент сокеты для вас это лучшее решение, остальное это так, прошлое... К которому лучше не возвращаться.

Comment: После того, как сервер сделал `accept` мы получаем установленное TCP-соединение. Если его не разрывать, то как клиент, так и сервер могут посылать по нему данные. Таким образом, вы можете рассматривать в своей схеме первый send от клиента к серверу, как запрос на подписку на некоторые события. В дальнейшем (при изменении данных по этим событиям) сервер по своей инициативе может отправлять данные. Клиенту остается лишь читать их со своей стороны этого соединения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ведь и клиенту открыть сокет на вход, но разумно ли это, есть ли
>   такая практика вообще?

В протоколе SNMP абсолютно такая же ситуация. И там менеджер (клиент) слушает 162 порт, что бы получать незапланированные уведомления - trap-ы, которые в неопределённые моменты времени может отправлять ему агент (сервер).

Так что - вполне себе адекватное решение, проверенное миллион раз :-)